MySQL query - find repeat payers in a table for year and month
I am trying to find the number of members who have renewed their memberships for a given month and year. Members need to renew each year, and I would like to know for each month and year how many members:

In total paid for a membership
How many used a card to pay
How many used a coupon to pay
How many renewed their membership for that month / year (based on if there is already a previous entry for their member_id in the table)

I have these two queries which need to be combined. The first query is working fine. The second query has two placeholder values in square brackets [] that should be replaced with the month and year from the first query.
I have tried creating a temp table and then querying that but I keep getting a value of 0 for repeat payers.
SELECT 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) AS year,
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) AS month, 
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(coupon, '') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS card_payments,
  SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(coupon, '') != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS coupon_payments
FROM fees
WHERE status = 'succeeded'
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM fees 
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) = [month] 
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) = [year]
AND status = 'succeeded'
GROUP BY member_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

--- edit / solution ---
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temptable;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable (
  SELECT 
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) AS year,
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) AS month, 
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(coupon, '') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS card_payments,
    SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(coupon, '') != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS coupon_payments
  FROM fees
  WHERE status = 'succeeded'
  GROUP BY year, month
  ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
);

SELECT 
  t1.year,
  t1.month, 
  t1.total,
  t1.card_payments,
  t1.coupon_payments,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM fees 
    WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) = t1.month 
    AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) = t1.year
    AND status = 'succeeded'
    AND member_id IN (
      SELECT member_id
      FROM fees 
      GROUP BY member_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
  ) as total_repeat_payers,
  (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(member_id)
    FROM fees 
    WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) = t1.month 
    AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date)) = t1.year
    AND status = 'succeeded'
    AND member_id IN (
      SELECT member_id
      FROM fees 
      GROUP BY member_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
  ) as repeat_payers_ids
FROM temptable t1

Result looks like this:

